# Save image to photoGallery

Tags: ios, save, titanium, photo-gallery

```
var _picsTaken = 0;
var timer = {};




Titanium.Media.showCamera ({

saveToPhotoGallery: true,
allowEditing: false,
autohide:false, //Important!

success: function(event){



timer = setInterval(function(){
        Ti.Media.takePicture();
        if(_picsTaken++ > 5){
            clearInterval(timer);
            _picsTaken = 0;
        }
    }, 5000);


},

error: function(error){
    var a = Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({
        title: 'Camera'
    });
    if (error.code == Titanium.Media.NO_CAMERA || error.code == Titanium.Media.NO_VIDEO) {
        a.setMessage(L('no_camera'));
    }
    else {
        a.setMessage('Unexpected error: ' + error.code);
    }
    a.show();
},


cancel:function()
{
    Titanium.include('db.js');
},
});
```

I am trying to make an ios based app on titanium studio(1.7). What I am trying to do here is click pictures continuously automatically every 5 seconds and save it. But this code only saves the first picture. I have tried to change a lot in the code, but nothing seems to work. Please help me in this regard. I would really appreciate any sort of help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
success: function(event){
    Ti.Media.saveToPhotoGallery(event.media);
    timer = setInterval(function(){
        Ti.Media.takePicture();
        if(_picsTaken++ > 5){
            clearInterval(timer);
            _picsTaken = 0;
        }
    }, 5000);
},
```